# How to add bootstrap "data-" attr into data-table button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, datatables-1.10

I want to switch from using standard HTML button with a data-table button,  how can I add the bootstrap `data-toogle` & `data-target` attribute into a data-table button?

Any help is much appreciated

Bootstrap button

```
<button
    data-toggle="modal" data-target="#create_new_workorder"
    type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-warning btn-outline"><span
    class="hidden-md hidden-sm hidden-xs">Create Workorder</span> <i
    class="fa fa-fw fa-plus"></i>
</button>
```

Data-table Button :

```
buttons: [
    {
        text: 'New',
        action: function () {
            create_workorder_window();
        },
        className: 'btn btn-warning btn-outline'
    },
    { extend: 'colvis', text: 'Show', className: 'btn btn-warning btn-outline'}
],
```

javascript :

```
function create_workorder_window() {
    my_window = window.open("createworkorder", "create_workorder", ",toolbar=0,status=0,width=350,height=900");
```

Modal :

```
<!--Create Workorder Form Modal -->
<div class="modal fade " id="create_new_workorder" tabindex="-1" role="dialog"
     aria-labelledby="TitleLabel">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content modal-workorder">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&#xD7;</span></button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Create New Workorder</h4>
            </div>
            <form id="create_workorder" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">{% csrf_token %}
                <div class="modal-body">
                   {{ workorder_form.as_p }}
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit"
                           value="Create Workorder"/>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel
                    </button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: i think there is no option to add in custom attributes.you have to do that with jquery afer data table initialized

Comment: can you show me how to do it?

Comment: check this https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/36085/how-to-add-data-html-attribute-to-some-dt-button You have to add attributes after data table initialized

Comment: Thank you very much @XYZ found this discussion earlier, but I'm having trouble understanding it, but will continue reading it on

Comment: or perhaps you can help me with it if possible thanks.

Comment: Make a fiddle.I will have a look.Without the code i can`t do anything

Comment: Alright will do, give me a few minutes

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no way to add attributes nor `name` or `id` on a button natively through the API. The comments above is right, but the suggested solution in the link is way too over-cooked. Keep it simple, you really dont have to involve the API or the `Buttons` instance. Add a unique class to `className` and respond to the `init.dt` event to update the button with the desired attributes :

```js
$('#example').on('init.dt', function() {
   $('.my-text-button') 
     .attr('data-toggle', 'modal')
     .attr('data-target', '#create_new_workorder');  
});

var table = $('#example').DataTable( {
  dom: 'Bfrtip',
  buttons: [{
     text: 'New',
     action: function () {
       create_workorder_window();
     },
     className: 'btn btn-warning btn-outline my-text-button'
  }]
})
```

Comment: You could consider using [data](https://api.jquery.com/data/) instead of attr to keep it even simpler.

Comment: @Shiffty, Yes, so simple it will not work :) Have you ever tried...? It is a common misunderstanding.  Bootstrap does not use `data()` internally so using `data()` wont work. It will only work to *get* a `data-*` value. Try for yourself -> **http://jsfiddle.net/sLgofw7x/**

Comment: @Shiffty, No, It was a good suggestion, many people think `data()` can be used, I once did too.  Actually it has been proposed in rejected pull requests  -> **https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/pull/11100** `data()` is not a `data-*` attribute abstraction, but more a storage media provided by jQuery. `data()` does not actually set a `data-` value on the element.

Comment: sorry for the late reply but thank you so much @davidkonrad, this work!

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#myTable').DataTable( {
  buttons: [
    {
      extend: 'copyHtml5',
      attr:  {
        title: 'Copy',
        id: 'copyButton'
      }
    }
  ]
} );
```

https://datatables.net/reference/option/buttons.buttons.attr

I think there is a build in way to do this.